# Expression has an incorrect number of parameters for the function 'LookupSet'

Tags: reporting-services, expression, ssrs-2012, lookup

I have this Loockup custom code:

```
Function SumLookup(ByVal items As Object()) As Decimal
If items Is Nothing Then
Return Nothing
End If
Dim suma As Decimal = New Decimal()
Dim ct as Integer = New Integer()
suma = 0
ct = 0
For Each item As Object In items
suma += Convert.ToDecimal(item)
ct += 1
Next
If (ct = 0) Then return 0 else return suma 
End Function
```

Now I want to use in expression like:

```
=Code.SumLookup(LookupSet(Fields!sJerarquiaNivel2.Value,Fields!Unidad.Value,Sum(Fields!InventarioSobreVentas.Value, "DS_DataInventarioDosAniosAnterior"))
```

Problem is when I run project I getting:

> Expression has an incorrect number of parameters for the function 'LookupSet'

What am I doing wrong? Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to close the parentheses  at the end of the `SUM`

Try

```
LookupSet(Fields!sJerarquiaNivel2.Value,Fields!Unidad.Value,Sum(Fields!InventarioSobreVentas.Value), "DS_DataInventarioDosAniosAnterior")
```

Comment: I try but I get: Aggregate functions cannot be used for the destination or result Expression parameter of a lookup function

Comment: Ohh we can't sum to lookupset function. that's the problem.